# iview-ui - Can't get admin to go full height. iView example shows min-height: 200

Tags: vue.js, height, admin, iview-ui

Does anyone know why iView admin template only scales to preset height? Can anyone help me set the height of admin to be a full browser (100vh or 100%)?

Thank you in advance.

Example on the site shows predefined minHeight: 200px which only sizes up to that number.

Comment: Hi Did you find a way? Thanks

Comment: @VAAA No I did not (( No one, in their Q/A Chat, wants to talk to me in English. Maybe, if you speak Chinese you will have a better shot at it.

Comment: Yes I was thinking on using that so change my mind and will use element-ui.

Answer (score 0):

Your sider should be styled as

```
<Sider style="height: 100vh">...</Sider>
```